# How to change CustomFormat of multiple DateTimePicker fields in Winforms using foreach loop in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, datetimepicker

I am trying to change CustomFormat of multiple DateTimePicker components in my Winforms form. However when I create foreach loop I dont get option to change CustomFormat. Here is the code:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if(ctrl is DateTimePicker)
                {
                    ctrl.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
                }
            }
```

I am getting error: "'Control' does not contain a definition for 'CustomFormat' and no accessible extension method 'CustomFormat' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I am using VS 2022, and .NET CORE 6 (latest stable version).

Any help with this will be more than welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're still using variable "ctrl" which type is Control - not a DateTimePicker

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl is DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        dtp.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
    }
}
```

Should work just fine.